# React js Node API pagination not displaying the second set of data on next click

Tags: jquery, node.js, reactjs, api, pagination

I'm implementing react js table pagination for table of data coming from the Mysql database. Here in my database 13 columns are there on the first time i need to display 5 columns and clicking on next it should display next 5 and so on.

**React code:**

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {
  Container,
  Row,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  Button,
  FormLabel,
  Alert,
  Table
} from "react-bootstrap"
import Pagination from "react-js-pagination";


class EditBox extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: "",
      content: "",
      name: "",
      records: [], //data
      showAlert: false,
      alertMsg: "",
      alertType: "sucess",
      activePage: 1,
      itemsCountPerPage: 1,
      activePage: 15,
      totalItemsCount: 1,
      totalcount: "",
      page: 1,
      page_size: ""
    };

    this.handlePageChange = this.handlePageChange;
  }



  handleChange = (evt) => {
    this.setState({

      [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value,
    });

  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchAllRecords();
  }

  handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
    console.log(`active page is ${pageNumber}`);
    this.setState({
      activePage: pageNumber
    });
  }


  fetchAllRecords = () => {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    fetch(`http://localhost:5001/viewtable?page=${5}&page_size=${0}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers,
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log("resultt", result.totalcount);
        this.setState({
          records: result.response,
          totalcount: result.totalcount,
        });

      })
      .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
  };

  render() {
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      Container > {
        this.state.showAlert === true ? ( <
          Alert variant = {
            this.state.alertType
          }
          onClose = {
            () => {
              this.setState({
                showAlert: false,
              });
            }
          }
          dismissible >
          <
          Alert.Heading > {
            this.state.alertMsg
          } < /Alert.Heading> < /
          Alert >
        ) : null
      }

      { /* All Records */ } <
      Row >
      <
      h2 > Content Table < /h2> <
      Table striped bordered hover size = "sm" >

      <
      thead >
      <
      tr >
      <
      th > id < /th> <
      th > Title < /th> <
      th > Content < /th> <
      th > Action < /th> < /
      tr > <
      /thead>

      <
      tbody >

      {
        this.state.records.map((record) => {
          return ( <
            tr >
            <
            th > {
              record.id
            } < /th> <
            th > {
              record.title
            } < /th> <
            th > {
              record.content
            } < /th>

            <
            /tr>

          );
        })
      } <
      /tbody> 


      <
      /Table>

      <
      /Row>

      <
      div > < Pagination activePage = {
        this.state.activePage
      }
      itemsCountPerPage = {
        5
      }
      totalItemsCount = {
        this.state.totalcount
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handlePageChange.bind(this)
      }
      /> < /
      div >


      <
      Row >
      <
      Form >
      <
      FormGroup >
      <
      FormLabel > Enter Title < /FormLabel> <
      FormControl type = "text"
      name = "title"
      placeholder = "Enter Title"
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      value = {
        this.state.title
      } > < /FormControl> < /
      FormGroup > <
      FormGroup >
      <
      FormLabel > Enter Content < /FormLabel> <
      FormControl type = "text"
      name = "content"
      placeholder = "Enter Content"
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      value = {
        this.state.content
      } > < /FormControl> < /
      FormGroup > <
      /Form> < /
      Row > <
      /Container> < /
      div >
    );
  }


}

export default EditBox
```

Here i only added the part for fetch records from the database and display.

The issue i'm facing is i can't display the next columns after the first 5 columns on next click. I need to change the code in such a way that on next click it should display next 5 datas. I need to do it dynamically without using hooks concept.

Here is the API call im using with the LIMIT and OFFSET

```js
app.get('/viewtable', (req, res) => {
  console.log('datassss', req.query);
  let sql = `SELECT *FROM table_content LIMIT ${req.query.page} OFFSET ${req.query.page_size} `;
  let query = con.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(JSON.stringify({
      status: 200,
      error: null,
      response: result,
      totalcount: result.length
    }));
  });
});
```

Other than this do i need to add any other query for fetch the data on second click?.

**Table image:**
[image]

Do i need to do any changes on API or front end to display the next page?
Any suggestions will be helpful for me.

Comment: What is your `req.query.page` and `req.query.page_size` from the frontend ? I can't see any passed arguments in the `fetchAllRecords`.

Comment: req.query.page=>LIMIT req.query.page_size=>OFFSET, YOU CAN SEE IT in API, not passing any arguments in that function. could you suggest the changes?